# giving a socket descriptor value greater than 1024 in select

Tags: sockets

Before calling select socket call while doing FD_SET,if we set a descriptor value greater than 1024(FD_SETSIZE) is there any problem? Will it create any undefined behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the documentation for the OS where you are using `select`, but most likely it will. From Linux man pages:

> An fd_set is a fixed size buffer. *Executing* FD_CLR() or FD_SET() with
>   a value of fd that is negative or is equal to or *larger than
>   FD_SETSIZE* will result in **undefined behavior**. Moreover, POSIX requires
>   fd to be a valid file descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will either cause an error (perror = `EINVAL`) or cause a buffer overrun (reading outside the allocated buffer).

Many implementations allow `FD_SETSIZE` to be redefined to a greater value. Define it to a greater value before including socket.h and you should be fine. Just make sure you check the manual for your C compiler first.